# How to search a numeric column in teradata sql?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column in Teradata called `updated` with the `format '01/02/2015'`
Normally we can use a `where updated like '%[value]%'` to find a match. This does not seem to work with dates because it is a `numeric` column.

How to use `LIKE` operator in `Teradata SQL` to get list of updates by `year`?

I would like to get all the records for a particular year. In my cas `Like '%2015%'` does not work.

Comment: Before ask questions it's better to search on INTERNET

Comment: try yourself before asking question.@user88303

Comment: I did struggle with it myself. I will put in the error message so the effort can be seen.

Comment: One extra thing here since it wasn't mentioned in the comments or the answer. The field type you are dealing with here is not NUMERIC. It is DATE. As such the database knows how to interact with it as a date and there are many functions available that are DATE specific like `EXTRACT()` function mentioned in correct answer below.

Answer (score 3):

In teradata, If you need records for a particular year, you can use ANSI standard `extract` function to get `year` on a `date` column as below.

```
SELECT extract(YEAR
               FROM updated)
FROM t1;
```

Assuming from your question, that you need to retrieve all records for `year` `2015`, you can use `extract` in `where` clause as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE extract(YEAR
              FROM updated) = 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by zarruq is better since it treats the date like a date.  However, since you asked how to do it with a "like":

```
where cast(yourdatefield as varchar(10)) Like '%2015%'
```

In my example the value is no longer a date.  We converted it to varchar(10)...which will work with a "like"